# Name of special function used by Wolfram integrator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, notation, special-functions, wolfram-alpha

Integrating $e^{-r}/\sqrt{2t-r}$ with respect to $r$ between $r=t$ and $r=2t$ using [this widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605) gives the answer $2e^{-t}F(\sqrt{t})$. However the widget doesn't say what $F$ is.

I have looked on [Wolfram's documentation on common special functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialFunctions.html)
but there's nothing there resembling a plain $F$.

What is this function $F$?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is the [*Dawson Integral*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html). See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-r%29%2Fsqrt%282t+-+r%29%2C+%7Br%2C+t%2C+2t%7D

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. based on the graph, I imagine it's true that $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} t^3 e^{-t} F(\sqrt{t}) = 0 $ ??

Comment: also, is it $D_{+}$ or $D_{-}$?

Comment: Look at Dawson[Infinity] $= 0$, here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DawsonF.html, and see the def and limit here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit++%281%2F2%29+sqrt%28pi%29+e%5E%28-t%5E2%29+Erfi%5Bt%5D%2C+t+-%3E+Infinity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $F$ is the Dawson integral or Dawson function (references: [reference.wolfram.com](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DawsonF.html), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)), given by
$$
F(x) = D_+(x) = e^{-x^2} \int_0^x e^{t^2}dt.
$$

You can find this out by using the [main Wolfram Alpha interface](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) rather than the widget you linked to (the circled text below will be interactive):

[image]

---

Remarks on a few properties of $F$, since you expressed an interest in the comments:

Clearly $F(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. So to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=0$, it suffices to show that given a fixed $\epsilon > 0$, we have $F(x) < 2\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Since $t \mapsto e^{t^2-x^2}$ is an increasing function $[0, x] \to (0,1]$,
$$
F(x)
= \int_0^{x-\epsilon} e^{t^2 - x^2} dt + \int_{x-\epsilon}^x e^{t^2 - x^2} dt
< x e^{(x-\epsilon)^2-x^2} + \epsilon.
$$
Now
$x e^{(x-\epsilon)^2-x^2} = x e^{- 2x\epsilon + \epsilon^2} = \frac{\exp(\epsilon^2)}{2\epsilon} y e^{-y}$ where we have set $y = 2\epsilon x$. Thus we can use the fact that $\lim_{y \to \infty} y e^{-y} = 0$ to obtain the desired bound.

As a consequence, $\lim_{t \to \infty} t^3 e^{-t} F(\sqrt t) = 0$ because both $t^3 e^{-t}$ and $F(\sqrt t)$ tend to $0$ as $t \to \infty$.